# Global variable Cloudify

Tags: cloudify

During the life cycle of my node template (type: cloudify.aws.nodes.Instance), I create a variable.

It is possible in another node template (type: cloudify.aws.nodes.Instance) that has no relationship with the first, get that variable?

There is the possibility of setting a global variable that can be accessed during any stage of the life cycle Cloudify?

Answer (score 3):

As of Cloudify 3.3, you cannot set global variables in the context. You need a relationships between two node-instances to access the runtime-properties of each.

However, inside of a blueprint you can use the [get_attribute intrinsic function](http://docs.getcloudify.org/3.3.0/blueprints/spec-intrinsic-functions/#get-attribute) as an input to scripts and workflow operations.

Comment: I'm using the Cloudify CLI 3.2.1 version. How do I set global variables in the context?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the "runtime property" of a node_template which can be accessed inside another node_template using:
(Assuming you want to fetch the variable from node1 to node2)

node2:
.
.
properties :
  host_name : { get_attribute: [node1, ] }

NOTE: make sure the node1's runtime variable is set before this node is configured else you will get an error.
Therefore I would advise you to create a relationship between node2 and node1.
That is node2 depends_on node1.